# C# Checking if text-based answer is correct

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, analysis

Good day all. Say I have a question:

> What is a reverse reaction?

And the answer to this question is:

> A reverse reaction is a reaction in which the products react to form
>   reactants and vise versa.

Now what would be the best way to determine if a user-inputted answer this question is correct or not? I can think of a couple of ways but they aren't practical.

**One of the ways:**

```
string answer = "A reverse reaction is a reaction in which the products react to form reactants and vise versa.";
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input.Equals(answer))
{
    //answer is correct
}
```

**Other way:**

Checking to see how many words match and getting a percentage from that. If it calculates to a certain percentage then the answer is right.

```
Number of words: 17 
Number of words in input that match answer: 17 
Correctness percentage: 100%
```

**Another way:**

Check to see if the input contains certain key phrases.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] keyPhrases = new string[] { "Products react to form reactants" };
foreach (string keyPhrase in keyPhrases)
{
    if (!input.Contains(keyPhrase))
    {
        //answer is incorrect
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use radio buttons and a multiple choice test. Do not try to replace human professors :)

Comment: This is very difficult to do it right. Something in the realm of AI. Probably this is the reason that every on-line questionnaire are based on a list of possible answers where the user chooses the right one

Comment: The other solutions are bound to fail. For instance, your "correctness percentage" approach would have a hard time differentiating *A reverse reaction is a reaction in which the products react to form reactants and vice versa* from *A reverse reaction is a reaction in which the products* ***do not*** *react to form reactants and vice versa*.

Comment: When you say correctness, does it mean *semantically* correct? If it does, there is no simple way at this moment to do that...

Comment: You can check if some predefined keywords are used in the answer

Comment: Use natural language processing... :)

Comment: @Nacho It seems very relevant to this context. Will do some research on it some time later today. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean by correctness is *semantically correct*, **and** the user is **free** to put up his answer, then I believe there is **no simple way** at this moment to do that by programming *at all*.

1. If you do it with the first way:

   ```
   string answer = "A reverse reaction is a reaction in which the products react to form reactants and vise versa.";
   string input = Console.ReadLine();
   if (input.Equals(answer))
   {
       //answer is correct
   }
   ```

   And the user forgot to put the last little dot ".",

   ```
   "A reverse reaction is a reaction in which the products react to form reactants and vise versa"
   ```

   then he will get **wrong**, but he is actually correct
2. If you do it the second or the third way, then if the user simply mentions its **negation**, he may have high percentage of match *but* totally wrong in his concept:

   ```
   "A reverse reaction is NOT a reaction in which the products react to form reactants and vise versa"
   ```

As of now, I believe the best way to do this is by **restricting** the user inputs to multiple choices provided by you.

And one of the best items to do this is the radio buttons. But you could do this by `combo box and button` or `ListBox which allows single/multiple choices` as you want it, but the bottom line is the same:

> **restrict your user inputs or you cannot tell whether his answer is** semantically right/wrong easily.

It may require expertise in grammatical understanding, lots of dictionary words, complex words-meanings relationship models, and excellent background contexts interpretations otherwise.

---

That being said,

Regex cannot help to check if an answer is *semantically* correct - it can only help you to find a *pattern* which you may use to *check* if the user puts a semantically correct answer.

Thus...

If it is used together with human inspection, then probably your second and third ways + Regex would give some benefits.